# Trying to display data from an object to an unordere list. Nothing Showing

Tags: meteor, reactjs

searchresults is an object(json data) Im trying to show the data in an unordered list. Nothing is showing up. Not sure why.. Ive set the json data in a session, like Session.set("searchresults", data); the data is saved and doing a console.log(console.log(searchresults[0].snippet.title); works.

```
 searchList = React.createClass({

   renderSearches() { 
    var searchresults = Session.get('searchresults');

     return 
     Object.keys(searchresults).map(function (key) {    
       return <SearchItem search={searchresults[key]} />;
     });


   },

   render: function() {
     return  (
     <div>
     <ul>
        {this.renderSearches()}
      </ul>
      </div>

     );
    }
 });





SearchItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

return (
  <li > <strong>{this.props.search.snippet.title}</strong> </li>
);
  }
 })
```

Comment: You're mixing ES5 and ES6. You're not assigning the result of `Session.get('searchresults');` to anything. You have a new line between the return and `Object.keys`. There's a whole heap of errors, fix them first otherwise it'll be hard to debug for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to `return` `SearchItem`.

`return <SearchItem search={searchresults[key]} />`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Road answer's, in your `SearchItem`, you can't access to `searchresults[key]`. 
If you say:

```
<SearchItem search={searchresults[key]} />;
```

You have to use the `props` of your SearchItem component.

```
SearchItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <li><strong>{this.props.search.snippet.title}</strong> </li>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Ive made the changes. still nothing.

Comment: Can you show us your code now ?
Here is an example that works : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/28096/

Comment: My link didn't help you ?